# How to convert pdf documents to html files?

Tags: pdf-to-html

Should remain format,looks almost the same as original.

Comment: Are you looking for something the online or downloadable converters found by Google don't provide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of examples:

[This page](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/howto-convert-pdf-files-to-html-files.html) discusses how to use software called *pdftohtml* to convert in Ubuntu.

[This page](http://www.topshareware.com/convert-pdf-to-html/downloads/1.htm) lists shareware (probably Windows) which converts PDF to various MS formats, including *htm*.

I even found a couple of videos (a Google video and one on www.break.com). I didn't look at them because I think they'll just describe how to use some software.

These are obviously unsatisfactory if you want to know how to do it yourself.

I think PDF started out as a compressed 'postscript' file, but these days would probably contain images (of scanned documents, for example).

If that's the case, don't bother looking for text, you can extract the images and create HTML pages to display the images. This should at least enable you to preserve the formatting.

At the very least, you could screen-capture the PDF pages to create the images. Crude, I know, but it would work whether the PDF was postscript or images.